Bounding the integral $\int_{a}^b t^{-1 + \delta } e^{2 \pi i t} dt$
Let $1 < b$ and $0 < \delta \leq 1/2$. I would like to show that the integral
$$
\left| \int_{1}^b t^{-1 + \delta } e^{2 \pi i t}\; dt\right| 
$$
is bounded uniformly for any $1 < b$.
I would appreciate any suggestions on how to get started!
Thank you!

Why do you have $\frac{1}{k}$ in your title, but $\delta$ in your actual question?

We show $F(x):=\int_{1}^x t^{-1+\delta} e^{2\pi i t}dt$ is bounded over $[0, \infty)$.
When $0\le x \le 1$,
$$|F(x)|\le\int_x^1 |t^{-1+\delta} e^{2\pi i t}|dt =\int_x^1 t^{-1+\delta}dt = \frac{t^{\delta}}{\delta}|_x^1=\frac{1-x^{\delta}}{\delta}\le \frac{1}{\delta}$$
For $x\in [1, \infty)$, use integration by parts,
$$2\pi i F(x)=\int_1^x t^{-1+\delta}de^{2\pi i t}=t^{-1+\delta} e^{2\pi i t}|_1^x - \int_1^x e^{2\pi i t} (t^{-1+\delta})'dt$$
We bound the two parts separately. When $x\ge 1, 0<x^{-1+\delta}\le 1$ as $-1+\delta\le0$, so
$$\big|t^{-1+\delta} e^{2\pi i t}|_1^x\big| \le |x^{-1+\delta} e^{2\pi i x}| + 1=x^{-1+\delta}+1\le 2$$
$$|\int_1^xe^{2\pi i t} (t^{-1+\delta})'dt |\le \int_1^x|e^{2\pi i t} (t^{-1+\delta})'|dt=\int_1^x|(t^{-1+\delta})'|dt =1 - x^{-1+\delta} < 1$$
(Note that $t^{-1+\delta}$ is montone and converges to $0$, while $\int_a^b e^{2\pi i t}dt$ is uniformly bounded. In the discrete case, this is just the Dirichlet's test for series, and the proof are essentially the same.)
We are done. Actually we only need $0< \delta \le 1$, and we have for all $x\ge 0$, $$|F(x)|\le \max (\frac{1}{\delta}, |\frac{3}{2 \pi i}|)=\frac{1}{\delta}$$

Lemma. $t^x-(t+\frac12)^x\le-\frac{xt^{x-1}}{2}$ for any $t>0$ and $x<0$.
Proof: It's equivalent to $(t+\frac12)^x\ge t^x+\frac{xt^{x-1}}{2}$, which is obvious by Newton's Binomial Theorem.
Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfies $b\le k<b+1$.
$$
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_1^bt^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t\right|=&\left|\int_1^{k}t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t-\int_b^{k}t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t\right|\\
\le&\left|\int_1^{k}t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t\right|+\left|\int_b^{k}t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t\right|\\
\le&\left|\int_1^{k}t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t\right|+\int_b^{k}\left|t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\right|\mathrm{d}t\\
\le&\left|\int_1^{k}t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t\right|+\int_b^{k}1\mathrm{d}t\\
\le&\left|\int_1^{k}t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t\right|+1\\
=&\left|\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\int_n^{n+1}t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t\right|+1\\
\le&\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\left|\int_n^{n+1}t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t\right|+1\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\left|\int_n^{n+\frac12}t^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it}+(t+\frac12)^{-1+\delta}e^{2\pi it+\pi i}\mathrm{d}t\right|+1\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\left|\int_n^{n+\frac12}(t^{-1+\delta}-(t+\frac12)^{-1+\delta})e^{2\pi it}\mathrm{d}t\right|+1\\
\le&\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\int_n^{n+\frac12}\left|(t^{-1+\delta}-(t+\frac12)^{-1+\delta})e^{2\pi it}\right|\mathrm{d}t+1\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\int_n^{n+\frac12}t^{-1+\delta}-(t+\frac12)^{-1+\delta}\mathrm{d}t+1\\
\mathop{\le}\limits^{(\text{by lemma})}&\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\int_n^{n+\frac12}\frac{(1-\delta)t^{\delta-2}}{2}\mathrm{d}t+1\\
\le&\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{(1-\delta)t^{\delta-2}}{2}\mathrm{d}t+1\\
=&\int_1^k\frac{(1-\delta)t^{\delta-2}}{2}\mathrm{d}t+1\\
=&\frac{3-k^{\delta -1}}{2}\\
<&\frac32
\end{align*}
$$
Which is a constant, so the integral is bounded uniformly for any $1<b$.
